# Django keep database state while atomic transaction

Tags: python, django, atomic

I'm facing an issue I have no clue to solve it.

The whole part of a code is encapsulated into a `with transactions.atomic()` ensuring that if something fails, then the database won't be modified and will be restored to the previous state.

That is working. But what I'd like is during the whole execution of the code, the state of the Db is not changing, that way if I change a model during that atomic transaction, it won't be saved before the end of the atomic transaction, and I still can acces its "previous" state during the transaction atomic.

Is there a way to achieve that in python/django ?

I think it's kind of "idempotent" right ?

Thank you a lot for your help !